# Trying to scrape text from div tag, but get Nonetype

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, scrape

i am scraping a realestate website in python and im stuck trying to scrape the company name of the agents. I get a AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text.

[image: This is the snapshot of the text i want to scrape]

[image: this is the error i get running my code] Any help is appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.point2homes.com/MX/Real-Estate-Listings.html?LocationGeoId=&LocationGeoAreaId=&Location=San%20Felipe,%20Baja%20California,%20Mexico"
page_scrape = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_scrape.content, 'html.parser')

lists = soup.find_all('article')

for list in lists:
    address = list.find('div', class_="address-container").text
    try:
        beds = list.find('li', class_="ic-beds").text
    except:
        print("Data Not Logged")
    try:
        baths = list.find('li', class_="ic-baths").text
    except:
        print("Data not logged")
    try:
        size = list.find('li', class_="ic-sqft").text
    except:
        print("Data not logged")
    type = list.find('li', class_="property-type ic-proptype").text
    price = list.find('span', class_="green").text
    agent = list.find('div', class_="agent-name").text
    firm = list.find('div', class_="agent-company").text

    info = [address, beds, baths, size, type, price, agent, firm]

    print(info)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code and errors as text and not as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look like beautiful soup not work correctly with standart tag format but when you try print firm without .text the data is exist so u can do simple substring operation :

i try is work here the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = "https://www.point2homes.com/MX/Real-Estate-Listings.html?LocationGeoId=&LocationGeoAreaId=&Location=San%20Felipe,%20Baja%20California,%20Mexico"

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0","Content-Type": "application/json"}

page_scrape = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_scrape.content, 'html.parser')

lists = soup.find_all('article')

for list in lists:
    address = list.find('div', class_="address-container").text
    try:
        beds = list.find('li', class_="ic-beds").text
    except:
        print("Data Not Logged")
    try:
        baths = list.find('li', class_="ic-baths").text
    except:
        print("Data not logged")
    try:
        size = list.find('li', class_="ic-sqft").text
    except:
        print("Data not logged")
    type = list.find('li', class_="property-type ic-proptype").text
    price = list.find('span', class_="green").text
    agent = list.find('div', class_="agent-name").text
   
    firmstr = list.find('div', class_="agent-company")
    firm=''
    
    if firmstr is not None:
        spl_word = '>'
        firmstr2=str(firmstr)
        res = firmstr2.split(spl_word, 1)
        splitString = res[1]
        
        res2 = splitString.split('<', 1)
        splitString2 = res2[0]
       
        firm=splitString2
    
   
    info = [address, beds, baths, size, type, price, agent, firm]

    print(info);
```

Comment: thank you, you are a godsend. This has been driving me nuts for the last two days. I appreciate your help so much.